# What it means to connect two nodes without a relation?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, graphdb

I have written below three queries and trying to understand difference between all 3 of them.

Query1:

```
MATCH (person)-[r]->(otherPerson)
```

Query2:

```
MATCH (person)-->(otherPerson)
```

Query3:

```
MATCH (person)--(otherPerson)
```

Please let me know if there is any difference between the three queries.

Answer (score 2):

Query 1 and 2 are basically the same, you are asking for all nodes connected by relationships that start at the `person` nodes and end at the `otherPerson` node.  In Query 1 you are also adding an alias/label to the actual relationship `r` that would allow you to return the relationship.  In Query 1 you could do

```
MATCH (person)-[r]->(otherPerson) RETURN r
```

In Query 2, you could not return the relationship.

Query 3 is similar to Query 2 except that you are asking for all nodes connected by relationships that start or end at the `person` nodes and start or end at the `otherPerson` node.

Query 1 and 2 will find all nodes and give them a label of `person`.  It will then go out all outbound relationships and label the connected node as `otherPerson`. In the case of Query 1 the relationship will also be given a label of `r`.

Query 3 will match the same pattern except it will traverse both incoming and outgoing edges to find the `otherPerso`  node.

Comment: Is `MATCH (:person)-[:r]->(:otherPerson) RETURN r` correct? Should we have `[r]` instead of `[:r]`?

Comment: Also, you have mentioned `Let's say you had a relationship such as follows:` but I don't see any `relationship`

Comment: I updated the answer to provide more clarity.